# save the results of a datalayer locally

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

If we use the `google tag manager` we can implement a datalayer.

We can see the values of this datalayer if we go to chrome --> make right click --> inspect elements --> console and type dataLayer.

Is it possible to save this values of dataLayer locally?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly! You can presust the $dataLayer$ using a number of methods.

The simplest is to use $cookies$. However cookies can be deleted, cannot be encrypted and have a 4k size limit. They are also sent to the server with every http request. Cookies are strings and you will need to parse them get at your data.

A second option is using the web storage api. If you need to persist for just the session use the $sessionStorage$ interface but if you need to perssist the data for longer you need to uses the %localStorage$ inteface. With webstorage data is only avaialable client side. You can sotre total of 5MB per domain and you can store key value pairs of data without parsing.

For more information on how to do this via GTM you can look at [this Blog Post](http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/two-ways-to-persist-data-via-google-tag-manager/) by Simo Ahava which contiains code samples too.

Comment: to be more specific is it possible to have a list of urls which have this dataLayer and save this key/values into a local file without need to open a browser?

Comment: you can define a lookup table in GTM add a script store it dynamicaly into the dataLayer. But all this will only happen once the browser accesses the site